# iOS - UITableView - numRowsInSection differs to cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm having a little trouble with my UITableView.
I'm loading the tableView with some JSON returned from our server.

**JSON** [Link to Pastebin >](http://pastebin.com/TmtawQya)

(I've removed some items for readability as it contained hundreds)
This is the print_r() output from PHP.

As you can see it's using sub arrays.
When I log sections and counts from numberOfRowsInSection, this is correct.

Eg,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if([tableView isEqual: self.timetableTableView]){

        NSDictionary *sectionContents = [_timetableDataArray objectAtIndex: section];
        NSLog(@"Section: %d, count: %d", section, [sectionContents count]);

        return [sectionContents count];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Returns,

```
Section: 6, count: 12
Section: 0, count: 35
Section: 1, count: 35
Section: 2, count: 38
Section: 3, count: 33
Section: 4, count: 19
Section: 5, count: 15
```

So far so good.
The table view also draws the correct amount of sections and cells, per section.

Now, my problem is in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
It's not being called the amount of times i'd expect. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if([tableView isEqual: self.timetableTableView]){

        static NSString *TimetableCellIdentifier = @"TimetableTableCell";
        TimetableTableCell *cell = (TimetableTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TimetableCellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil){

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimetableTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }


        // Get the day array out of my JSON.
        NSDictionary *dayContents = [_timetableDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSLog(@"Row: %d, Path: %d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section);

        return cell;
    }
}
```

This logs,

```
Row: 0, Path: 0
Row: 1, Path: 0
Row: 2, Path: 0
Row: 3, Path: 0
Row: 4, Path: 0
Row: 5, Path: 0


numberOfSectionsInTableView returns the correct amount of sections.
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {

        if([tableView isEqual: self.timetableTableView]){
            NSLog(@"sections: %d", [_timetableDataArray count]);
            return [_timetableDataArray count];
        }
        return 0;
    }

sections: 7
```

As far as I can tell, cellForRowAtIndexPath is iterating over the days array in my JSON only .
Although it has the correct amount of sections/cells in numberOfRowsInSection.

How can I tell cellForRowAtIndexPath to iterate over the days array (section) contents?

Is it possible to loop through sub arrays with UITableViews?

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Did you implement numberOfSectionsInTableView ?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is only called for the *currently visible* cells. What happens if you scroll down in the table view?

Comment: Mike, I've updated my post with extra code. numberOfSectionsInTableView returns the correct amount of sections.

Comment: @MartinR, Ah I see! I didn't realise it changed the rows/path as you scrolled. I think this is it. stupid me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no error. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called "on demand" for the currently visible cells. When you scroll down, it will be called for the remaining cells.